# Printing all the List Information into a PDF file

Tags: list, printing

Is there a way to print out all the List information inside each individual List (Under the setting section) for all the List inside a site into a PDF file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about Printing the list items, from an option which could be present in the settings page of the list.

There is no out of the box option from MOSS, where you could do that. But gladly, there is a codeplex tool called [SPPrintlist](http://spprintlist.codeplex.com/), which can serve your purpose. It has pretty neat options of printing with pagination and sorting too. Check it out.

Comment: actually, I am referring to the field names inside the setting page. (I am not referring to the data, or the list items). Currently, I go to each individual list's setting and print out. I have a lot of lists and it could take half a day or more before I finish print out all the settings. So, I was wondering if there is a better way that we can print it out by using Sharepoint designer (as our system admin do not allow access to their server other than using SharePoint Designer)

Answer (score 0):

Amongst many other things, the PDF Converter for SharePoint allows any page to be converted to PDF directly from the [SharePoint UI](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html), [SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/converting-sharepoint-lists-to-pdf.html), [Nintex Workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/08/convert-html-to-pdf-using-nintex.html) or a [web service call](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html).

I worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.